# How to hide columns on datagridview database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Please help i want to hide the a column in my datagridview but accessible when clicking it (selected cell) Here is my code for showing data on datagridview:

```
Private Sub showdata()

    Dim dbcommand As String
    dbcommand = "SELECT ID, First_Name, Second_Name, Dob, ID_Card_No, Email FROM UsersTB"
    adt = New OleDbDataAdapter(dbcommand, dbconn)
    datatable = New DataTable
    adt.Fill(datatable)
    dgvusers.DataSource = datatable

End Sub
```

This is my code for filling textbox on cell select

```
Private Sub dgvusers_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvusers.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = dgvusers.CurrentRow.Index
    txtID.Text = dgvusers.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
End Sub
```

Now i want to hide the ID column on datagridview so users can't see it but when the cell is selected it fill the textbox on txtID.Text.
Is there any simple code that could set the ID column on visible = False?

Answer (score 0):

Found it xp

dgvusers.Columns("ID").Visible = False

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code to populate the `TextBox`.  Just bind it to the `DataTable` too:

```
dgvusers.DataSource = datatable
dgvusers.Columns(0).Visible = False
txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", datatable, "ID")
```